# How to use Liferay's blade CLI in a Shell Script?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-blade-cli

I'm trying to call the Liferay blade CLI within a shell script. The script should help the user to do some work.

The script should:

1. Change to the Liferay workspace
2. Change the user XY
3. Execute the blade command as user XY.

Is there a way to implement such a script?

Answer (score 0):

Try this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo -H -E -i -u userXY bash -c "cd '/path/to/liferay-workspace'; blade ${*}"
```